# CakePHP: Sending Email From Wamp Shows Error Internal Error

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to send email in Cakephp using WAMP. I copied the code from CAKEPHP website but it does't seem to work and it does't provide any helpful information to debug.

This is the error with no further information I have debug kit installed but it also does't show any information.

**

```
SMTP timeout.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

**

In Controller I have

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
```

in my function inside controller I have

```
public function contact(){

        $email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
        $email->to('shahid.abdullah.android@gmail.com');
        $email->subject('Email testing Subject');
        $email->send('Email testing content');

    }
```

In app/config/email.php I have

```
<?php
class EmailConfig {

    public $gmail = array(
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password**',
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'tls' => true
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing `smtp.gmail.com` to `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` and remove `'tls' => true`.

Also you might want to try having a from paramaeter in your `contact()` function such as:

```
$email->from('example@domain.com');
```